# easy way to flag library functions as deprecated / forbidden in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a mixed Java / Kotlin project in Android studio with the usual bunch of androix libraries.

Is there an easy way (short of writing custom lint/detekt/ktlint rules) to essentially deprecate certain usages of third party libraries? Assuming I have no way of actually changing the code in the library itself.

For example, the library has a method `foo`, I'd like all usages of that method to be flagged and break the build.

Comment: of third party libraries? Not from your own code? why would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `ForbiddenImport` rule in *detekt*.

```yaml
# detekt.config

ForbiddenImport:
    active: true
    imports:
        - 'kotlinx.android.synthetic.*'
        - 'com.example.3rdParty'
```

You can also exclude some classes from auto-import and completion. `Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import`
This is just for developers not find the 'deprecated' or 'unwanted' imports easily.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Neat! With https://detekt.dev/docs/rules/style/#forbiddenmethodcall I can also directly monitor usages of the forbidden methods. This looks like what I needed. Thanks!